# View Composer for sidebar in Laravel

Tags: laravel

using a view composer for the first time in Laravel.  i have a sidebar that is included in every step of a submission form process a user goes through.  i want the sidebar to have link that apply to the proper submission (i.e. if this is submission number 5, the links in the sidebar should all go to the edit function for submission 5.

i have the following code in my web.php:

```
View::composer('layouts.planbuilder', function($view){
$plansubmissions = PlanSubmission::find(3);
$view->with('plansubmissions', $plansubmissions) ;
```

}) ;

i am able to access the $plansubmissions variable, but of course this only applies to submission 3, which i hard coded in.  is it possible to get the logic from another controller?  i can't just get the user id with Auth because a user can have many submissions

Comment: Hey Alexander! You ask a ton of questions on SO but never accept any answers. If you find that these answers are assisting you ( _I can see they are, judging by the evolution of your questions_ ) you should mark them as accepted. This way, future answer seekers can benefit from the community.

Comment: Thanks for telling me.  i am new to programming and stackoverflow.  i didn't realize there was an accept button.  i will go update those now

Comment: No worries at all! Welcome to the community - we're happy to have you! [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is a good reference point for what you should do when someone answers.

Comment: Reviewing all the information provided in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) will help you to structure your questions for the best chance at receiving assistance from everyone as well.

Answer (score 1):

View Composers also have access to the variables that were passed to the view itself, so if you are passing the submission to your view from the controller like so

```
return view('submissions.show', compact('submission');
```

Then in your composer you can assign it to `$plansubmissions`

```
$plansubmissions = $view->getData()['submission'];
```

Comment: `data` is protected .. maybe `$view->getData()`, `$view->submission` or `$view['submission']`?

Comment: Yeah, $view->getData()['submission'] should work. Forgot it was protected and that it's an array not a collection. I'll update my answer